# SpringBoot console application don't log to console anything

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to make spring boot console application. I've added to my pom.xml these lines:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

            <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I've added log4j2.xml file to my resources folder:

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="log"
              immediateFlush="true" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern=
                                   "%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And my Main looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Main.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
        LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
    }
```

The problem is that when I run the application from terminal, I've got some logs and warning printed out to console and I don't want this behavior:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (jar:file:/Users/robert.cebula/Projects/expense_summary/target/expense_summary-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Do you know what can I do to get rid off these lines printed to console. I would like nothing to be printed to console by spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot has a logback file built in.

You need to overwrite it by creating your own `logback.xml` file. You can read more about creating a logback file for spring [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).

I would advise to write logs to a file instead of not having any log at all.